# Can I store database connection strings and web service links in a different file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I found this link.  Very cool.  That shows how you can store appsettings in a different file:
http://sureshbeniwal.blogspot.com/2008/04/store-appsettings-in-external-file.html

Can I do the same thing with ConnectionStrings tag?

Can I do the same thing with web service links?

This is a web application so the web links are in this format:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <Webstrat.Web.Properties.Settings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All configuration section elements (such as `connectionStrings` etc) have the `configSource` attribute, [as discussed on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228167.aspx). This allows you to specify a separate file for inclusion, but not in the way you have shown.

Example:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes for connection strings. I have done it numerous times. Have not tried for web links, but you can check the schema for config and see if there is a file attribute for the settings. Since this appears custom, the answer depends on whether or not they coded the possibility in.

Answer (score 0):

using the [configSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228167.aspx) attribute works for most elements in the config file. I would recommend using that method instead of the file attribute in the example you posted.